# Dropbox core API

Tags: android, dropbox-api

I am linking my app to dropbox using the core API. When I install and start the app, my `onResume()` is fired. Then the dropbox link screen is displayed. When I press `Allow` my `onResume()` is never fired and the activity just closes.

Here is my activity in the `AndroiManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name="com.example.DeviceCheck"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And here is my `onResume()`:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d("ON_RESUME","true");
    super.onResume();
    AndroidAuthSession session = dropbox.getSession();
    if (session.authenticationSuccessful()) {
        try {
            session.finishedAuthentication();
            TokenPair tokens = session.getAccessTokenPair();
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(DROPBOX_NAME, 0);
            Editor editor prefs.edit();
            editor.putString(ACCESS_KEY, tokens.key);
            editor.putString(ACCESS_SECRET, tokens.secret);
            editor.commit();

            loggedIn(true);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error during Auth..", Toast.LENGHT_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

The `Log.d(...)` is never shown the second time. Do any of you have any suggestion? Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the logcat show when the app closes?

Comment: @JustinJasmann Nothing, not even the Log in the onResume, it just closes without ever going back to the activity. Mother of a mind boggle

Comment: Is there an `Activity.finish()` being called anywhere?

Comment: @JustinJasmann No, I checked and double checked. The only places where I call finish() is when I navigate to another activity and want to close this one